# Error 1 The type or namespace name 'FPSTimer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am following a code from Intel RealSense 3D camera. However I got this error. If I am supposed to add something to the Reference Assembly can you tell me what that is or how should this be fixed? This pertains to the FaceTracking example in the Intel RealSense 3D SDK Sample Browser.

```
private FPSTimer m_timer;
```

and here's the error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'FPSTimer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\users\mona\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\wfa1\wfa1\FaceTracking.cs   10  17  wfa1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you may or may not have the correct references installed, and then you need to add the proper `using` statement in your code file?

I don;t have this particular SDK on my machine, but there is some documentation available [HERE](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/2014gold/documentation/html/) which may be helpful. In particular, maybe [THIS](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/2014gold/documentation/html/index.html?devguide_csharp_application.html) section?